# Place download request in one tab but complete in another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

A web app opens new tab and places a POST request to the server to create a file for a download. Here is the code that sends the file back:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=name");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(zipPath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

What can happen is that the user can close the new tab and no download would take a place. Is there any chance that the app would still get the file? I understand that placing request in the app is the way to go, but I am dealing with existing architecture.

Thanks for help.

Just to point out that the files needs to created first hich take some time.

Comment: The app won't get the file either way. If the app is supposed to receive the file, you have to use ajax.

Comment: I am getting the file if I dont close the new tab.

Comment: You're getting it as download, right? But I though you are asking about the app getting the file? Also, the browser should start the download or open the "Save as" window immediately after opening the new tab. If the user wants to cancel the download, they have to actively do so by clicking "cancel" in the "save as" window or by canceling the actual download. Please clarify what you're asking here, because I have no idea what the issue is. -- I don't see how the user can cancel the download by closing the tab tbh

Comment: Unless your server is really slow and they have the chance to do so in between the tab opening and the download starting? Is this what this is about?

Comment: No, it is a download. I missed an important detail. The file needs to created first. I am updating my OP.

Comment: Ok, so there is a significant delay between the tab opening and the download starting? Either put a message into the tab that says "your file is being prepared, please don't close this tab". Or prepare the file first, and only trigger the download after. This takes some extra work though.

Comment: So, the bottom line is: once a tab is closed the file cannot be downloaded, right?

Comment: Afaik, if the server takes some time before sending a reply, and you close the tab before the browser receives the reply, then the request is basically canceled. Which means the download doesn't start. However: you can request the binary data via ajax, then trigger a browser download once the file was received in full. Here's how: https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/